# Prove, that when $n=p_{1}^{\alpha_{1}}...p_{n}^{\alpha_{n}}$ and $a, n$ are coprime then $a^{\psi{(n)}} \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, solution-verification

Prove, that when $n=p_{1}^{\alpha_{1}}...p_{n}^{\alpha_{n}}$ and $a,n$ are coprime then $a^{\psi{(n)}} \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$ where $\psi(n)=\text{lcm}.
(\phi(p_{1}^{\alpha_{1}}),...,\phi(p_{n}^{\alpha_{n}}))$

Here's my sketch of a solution:

Since a is coprime to n then a is coprime to all of the numbers in a prime representation of $n$. Therefore by Euler's theorem $a^{\phi(p_{i}^{\alpha_{i}})}\equiv 1 \pmod {p_{i}^{\alpha_{i}}}$ and the same is true if we take it to power which is a multiple of $p_{i}^{\alpha_{i}}$. So $\text{lcm}.
(\phi(p_{1}^{\alpha_{1}}),...,\phi(p_{n}^{\alpha_{n}}))$ also fullfils this condition and when $a^{X}\equiv 1 \pmod {p_{i}^{\alpha_{i}}}$ for all $p_{i}^{\alpha_{i}}$ then  $a^{X}\equiv 1 \pmod {n}$ $\blacksquare$.

Is this correct?

Comment: What about $n=6=2^13^15^07^011^013^0$ and $a=4$?

Comment: I'm so sorry, but I thought that \not| would come out of Latex as 'coprime' symbol.

Comment: Small comment: The argument is sound. However, one really should not use the symbol $n$ both for a number and the number of its prime divisors. It is, however, harmless, since one can use $a_i=0$ for $p_i$ that do not occur in the factorization of $n$.